# XSLT to HTML - div blank when converting

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert this XML into HTML, using the following XSLT file. But for some reason, it is not populating the `#juices` and `#smoothies` divs.
Tried many things, saw some examples, but still not managing to get this to work.
Sorry for so few details, but I have no idea what is wrong here.

Any help?

Links: 
[XML](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~rpedro02/xmfma/products.xml)
[XSL](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~rpedro02/xmfma/products.xsl)

Comment: Maybe you have some code?

Comment: Check the links on the question. Too long to paste here.

Comment: Too long to answer here... Show us what did you already have tried, what exactly is the problem. No one is going to solve your issue from scratch

Comment: Tried different XPath's, it seems not to catch the XML structure.

Comment: I would like to help you guys with more details, but not sure what to to.

Comment: Please give us an example of a desired output.

Comment: http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~rpedro02/xmfma/yumjuices/products.html

Like this (the first Mango Magic structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a namespace issue. Namespaces are a fundamental concept in XML. If you are not familiar with namespaces, please take time to learn and understand them.

Your input XML has a default namespace `<products xmlns="http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~rpedro02/ns/products">` which means that all elements belong to that namespace although they don't have a namespace prefix. XPath queries always need to be prefixed, if you are targeting elements in a certain namespace - the queries do not inherit the default namespace.

In your case this means that you need to declare the default namespace of your input XML with a prefix and then use that prefix when referring to any elements in your input XML document. Mainly this means altering the queries in the `<xsl:template match="/products/product">` template.

Some example code: declare the namespace like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:prod="http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~rpedro02/ns/products" >
```

And then use the prefix `prod` in your queries like this

```
<xsl:template match="/prod:products/prod:product">
    <div class="product">
        <img>
            <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="prod:name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="prod:picture"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
        ...
```

Comment: Many thanks! now I get it!
Just a quick question: how do I prefix attributes? Like here:
`<td><xsl:value-of select="@label"/></td>`

Comment: The default namespace does not apply to unprefixed attributes so there is no need to use a namespace prefix with them. In this case your problem is different, you are querying for a `label` attribute of a `<nutritional>` element but the attribute belongs to its child elements. Use `<xsl:for-each select="prod:nutritional/*">` instead.

Comment: Yep, noticed that after posting the comment and solved myself. But thanks again. Thought `<xsl:for-each select="prod:nutritional">` meant "for each of the elements of <nutritional>", but no. That's the problem of being used to use foreach in arrays on programming languages. :P

Answer (score 0):

it's working if I'm changing the

```
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <div id="juices" class="products">
                <h2>Juices</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[local-name()='product' and @type='juice']" />
            </div>
            <div id="smoothies" class="products">
                <h2>Smoothies</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//*[local-name()='product' and @type='smoothie']" />
            </div>
```

The xpath does not catch /products/product[@type= ...] ..

and changed the template that matching the products to be

```
<xsl:template match="./*[local-name()='product']">
    <div class="product">
```

Check the xsl and it's output [here](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cw/1)

Comment: It now evaluates and catches those conditions. But it is not applying correctly the templates. Seems to transform into plain text without the HTML tags. Any further help? Sorry, newbie here.

Comment: getting this error: E [Saxon6.5.5] Error in expression ./*[local-name()='product']: Unexpected token in pattern, found .

Comment: It "prints" the tags now, but they are empty. This is killing me... :S